# Which OS is used with CISCO SG300-XXX

Tags: cisco, switch

I can't find any infromation about which OS is used on the SG300-Switches by cisco, maybe you can help me with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cisco SG series doesn't use a full Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software IOS but a similiar one.
Being quite similiar they differ on a lot of stuff (VLAN management for one) 
SG series is aimed to small business, if you need a switch for cert study this is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title says SG300 and the posted question says SG3000. If you google "cisco sg300 firmware" it takes you directly to the download pages.

You can download the code for your model from here.

https://software.cisco.com/download/navigator.html?mdfid=283009439&flowid=49583

Comment: Thank you for that, didn't see that mistake in my question. I meant the SG300, so RobertoP gave me right the answer that I wanted, since I wasn't looking for updating the firmware, just for some information about it. But thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the operating system used in the small business series is vIOS.